# Mongodb replicaset with init scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on trying to get a MongoDB replicaset deployed into Kubernetes with a default set of collections and data.  The Kubernetes piece isn't too pertinent but I wanted to provide that for background.

Essentially in our environment we have a set of collections and data in the form of .js scripts that we currently build into our MongoDB image by copying them into /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/.  This works well in our current use case where we're only deploying MongoDB as a single container using Docker.  Along with revamping our entire deployment process to deploy our application into Kubernetes, I need to get MongoDB deployed in a replicaset (with persistent storage) for obvious reasons such as failover.

The issue I've run into and found recognized elsewhere such as this issue https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/339 is that scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ do not run in the same manner when configuring a replicaset.  I've attempted a few other things such as running a seed container after the mongo replicaset is initialized, building our image with the collections and data on a different volume (such as /data/db2) so that it persists once the build is finished, and a variety of scripts such as those in the github link above.  All of these either don't work or feel very "hacky" and I don't particularly feel comfortable deploying these to customer environments.

Unfortunately I'm a bit limited with toolsets and have not been approved to use a cloud offering like MongoDB Atlas or tooling such as the Enterprise Kubernetes Operator.  Is there any real supported method for this use case or is the supported method to use a cloud offering or one of the MondoDB operators?

Thanks in advance!